# Counterexample for closedness under union of $\prec_{\infty,\kappa}$ chains

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, counterexamples

Assume $\kappa$ is uncountable and $\phi$ is an $L_{\infty,\kappa}$ sentence. Let $K$ be the collection of models of $\phi$ partially ordered by $\prec_{\infty,\kappa}$. It is well-known that $K$ is closed under unions of increasing chains of length $\kappa^+$, but the argument fails for increasing chains of length $<\kappa$.

Do you have an easy counterexample, either for $\kappa=\aleph_1$ or $\kappa=\aleph_\omega$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In $L_{\infty,\kappa}$, you can express that a linear order has cofinality at least $\kappa$, since you can say that every less-than-size-$\kappa$ family is bounded. But having cofinality at least $\kappa$ is not generally preserved under unions of elementary chains of length $\lt\kappa$, although it would be for longer chains.

Comment: By longer chains, you mean chains of longer cofinality, right?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. But when it comes to unions-of-chains, it suffices to consider only chains whose length is a regular cardinal, since one can always go to a cofinal subchain, which has the same union.